# Data dump for closed public beta - Guitars - is not available?

Tags: support, area-51, data-dump, beta-phase, beta-sites

I am calculating the differences between graduated betas v.s. discontinued betas for an academic paper. In order to do so, I have located closed public betas and downloaded the data dumps from each proposal page.

All closed public betas have downloadable files except for one: the [Guitars](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6320/guitars) forum that was merged with another forum. Is it possible to get a data dump for Guitars like all the other sites (e.g. [economics](http://sstatic.net/area51/datadumps/052012%20Economics.zip))? If not, what options do I have in identifying which are the merged posts?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get a data dump for Guitars like all the other sites?

As far as I know, this isn't possible.

> If not, what options do I have in identifying which are the merged posts?

It's not likely you can find all merged posts in a simple way, but here's an idea to get started. Question #1 on Music Stack Exchange, [Criteria for selecting a voice teacher](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1/19800) was posted on April 26th, 2011. If you search for questions posted before that date with the query [`created:..2011-04-25 is:q`](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A..2011-04-25+is%3Aq), you get 374 results; questions which must have been posted on another site. You'll note that the [timeline](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/1061/timeline) and the [revision history](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/1061/revisions) of these questions do not mention any migration events, which is another sign of the sites having been merged.

Of course, if the sites coexisted for a while, it'll be much harder to weed the newest questions out. Something that might help is that the merge does not create new tags on the target site, and merge-migrated questions might end up getting [untagged]: https://music.stackexchange.com/revisions/1061/1.